# JavaScript effect of moving a div region to the left/right after an click-event on an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, effect

I have a question concerning Javascript: I want to have the same effect of moving photos to the left/right like flickr on his page (please, compare the header on their page http://www.flickr.com, if you click on one of the dots under the picture).

If you can show me how to do it with pure JavaScript, CSS or the JavaScript framework jQuery it would be very helpful for me!

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can use the `animate` function to animate a set of CSS properties. For example, to move an element 100 pixels to the left, taking 1000ms (1 second) to perform the animation:

```
$("#elementId").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=100"
    }, 1000, function() {
        //Complete
    }
);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/787ys/) for a working example.